# Как открыть .cs файл как Windows Form Constructor (Visual Studio c#) 2019

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Я создал пустой проект windows forms. В гайдах написано что вместе с файлом открывается и Windows Form constructor. Как его открыть как Windows Form constructor?

Абсолютно пустой проект.[image: c]

Comment: в VS 2019 дизайнер для форм "поломали" и до сих пор не починили. Только ждать или использовать VS 2017. Где-то попадалась ссылка на не русском по этому поводу, но уже не найду.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете платформу .NET Core, то Вам следует обновить VS до актуальной доступной версии. Дизайнер Windows Forms был добавлен в версии VS 2019 16.6.

Подробнее о дизайнере можно прочитать [тут](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/).

Answer (score 0):

ПКМ -> View designer. Или shift + F7.

Comment: Через Shift + F7 открывается копия файла без Windows Forms

Comment: Нажмите правой кнопкой на `Form1.cs` и вы увидите данную строку.

Comment: При нажатии на Открыть в конструкторе ничего не происходит. Переход просто к тому же файлу, но не как ни его открытие в конструкторе.

Comment: Обычно дизайнер должен открываться при двойном клике на форму. Если нет, то возможно вы как-то криво создали документ.

Comment: Т.е. https://imgur.com/SkxR051 этот шаблон? Я надеюсь...

Comment: Либо этот, либо .NET Framework. Зависит от ваших потребностей